# Charla sobre SOes en Bogotá, Colombia - 27 de abril de 2019

Tags: discusión, encuentros-locales

**Fecha:** 27 de Abril de 11:00am - 11:45am

**Dirección:** Carrera 8 # 40–52 en la Universidad Distrital, en Bogotá.

Estaré dando una pequeña charla con motivo del Festival Latinoamericano del Software Libre en su edición número 15.

La charla está orientada a dar a conocer StackOverflow en español a los estudiantes, pero cualquier persona interesada en asistir o dar una mano en la presentación es bienvenida.

Tendremos algunos regalos para los asistentes.

Para registrarse en el evento, pueden hacerlo en el siguiente enlace: https://flisolbogota.org/

Comment: ¡Mucho éxito! Si te hacen preguntas, recuerda pedirles un _Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable_ :P